# How should you create properties when using asyncio?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

When creating a class which uses asyncio I've found myself in a situation where a property getter needs to make an io operation. Therefore the function should be a coroutine. However awaiting a property feels unusual.

Here is a minimal working of example of what I mean. The code is valid and runs.

```py
import asyncio


class Person:
    """A class that represents a person"""

    def __init__(self, forename, surname):
        self.forename = forename
        self.surname = surname

    @property
    async def fullname(self):
        """Perform an io operation and return something.

        This could be looking something up in a database for example.        
        """
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        return f"{self.forename} {self.surname}"


async def main():
    john = Person("John", "Smith")

    # Let's print out the forename here, using the standard property format
    print(john.forename)

    # When printing the full name we must instroduce an await, which feels awkward.
    print(await john.fullname)


# Start the loop and run the main function
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

Is this the correct way of doing this?

Comment: A property should __not__ perform IO operations at all (nor any heavy computation FWIW).  Use a real method instead.

Comment: Thanks @brunodesthuilliers could you share some references for this statement? I'd be keen to learn more.

Comment: most obvious reference is pep08 (https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance): "Avoid using properties for computationally expensive operations; the attribute notation makes the caller believe that access is (relatively) cheap." - but it's really plain common sense: as the pep states, we (as developers) assume attribute access to be cheap and safe, so any operation that requires IO, heavy computation etc doesn't belong in a property.  FWIW, the mere idea of an "async property" strikes me as totally insane.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Feel free to throw that is as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: don't do this.

Longer answer: as [mentionned in pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#designing-for-inheritance):

> Avoid using properties for computationally expensive operations; the attribute notation makes the caller believe that access is (relatively) cheap.

So anything requiring IO is obviously not a candidate for a property. FWIW we don't only expect attributes access to be cheap, we also expect them to be safe (would you expect an attribute access to possibly raise an IOError, Database error, socket error or anything similar ?)

FWIW, you mention that "awaiting a property [feels unusual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)" which should already answer you question. Actually and as far as I'm concerned, the mere idea of an "async property" strikes me as just totally insane - properties are (semantically) about the object's state, and I just can't make sense of the concept of "async state".

Comment: Yep, browsing my own code I simply have an async load function which gets the object and fills in the properties for use and a save to commit changes to the backing store.

Answer (score 7):

> Is this the correct way of doing this?

It is, except for the stylistic question of whether a property *should* return an awaitable. The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54987177/1600898) argues against the practice on the grounds of common sense, but also based on the following quote from [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Avoid using properties for computationally expensive operations; the attribute notation makes the caller believe that access is (relatively) cheap.

As written, this does not imply that properties should not return awaitables, for two reasons:

- Accessing the property with the attribute notation is extremely cheap, because it only creates an *awaitable* (a coroutine object in case of a coroutine). It is only when you await the resulting object that you can suspend, and that is clearly marked with the use of an `await`.
- Awaiting something is not computationally expensive - in fact, doing something computationally expensive in a coroutine is forbidden because it would interfere with other tasks. An `await` either immediately returns the value, or it suspends the enclosing coroutine. The latter can certainly take *time* (but that is the whole point of using `await`), but it is definitely not *expensive* in terms of CPU.

I believe the idea behind the PEP8 warning is that a simple attribute access shouldn't result in state change or a long pause. As argued above, that holds for async properties as well, since the access only gives you the coroutine object. On the other hand, if you then go on to explicitly `await` that object, you're not only allowing, but actually requesting the resolution of the awaitable. This is not much different from how `<some list>.append` gives you the bound method object without doing anything, but if you then call that object, the call will change the list.

In conclusion, if returning an awaitable from a property "feels wrong", then  just don't do it, and use a method instead. But PEP 8 does not, as far as I can tell, oppose the practice.

Comment: That's an interesting POV. Just a note: pep8 doesn't explicitely warn against "async properties" indeed, but Python didn't have proper coroutines by that time either...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That's true. I think the idea behind the PEP8 warning is that a simple attribute access shouldn't result in state change or a long pause. As argued in the answer, that holds for async properties as well, since the access only gives you the coroutine object. On the other hand, if you then go on to explicitly `await` that object, you're not only allowing, but actually _requesting_ the resolution of the awaitable. This is not much different from how `l.append` gives you the method object without doing anything, but _calling_ that object changes the list.

Comment: With everything being an object, the difference between code and data is rather thin indeed, at least from a purely technical POV. From a more semantical POV, this difference still exists, and one expects a property to return data not code, so the comparison with `list.append` "giving you the method object" is IMHO debatable  (once again, you are right from a purely technical POV, it's a matter of semantics). If you go that way, a property is nothing but a method call in disguise so obviously the pep8's advice is based on semantics more than implementation...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I believe it is more than a technicality: `await` is an explicit keyword precisely so it is clear when the suspends can occur. It is a consequence of this design that you get to choose where the awaits occur, and the choice is obvious to the reader. When you specify `await resp.text`, the explicit `await` makes it crystal clear that you're going to the network and can suspend or receive an `IOError`.

Comment: This is still technicallity as far as I'm concerned. I'm talking semantic here. But I think we both made our point quite clear by now ;-)