# Running async code on demand from @property

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

    @property
    def show_list(self):
        if not self.mylist:
            asyncio.run(self.load_list())  # neither works?
            asyncio.create_task(self.load_list())
        return self.mylist

    async def load_list(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        self.mylist = [1]


async def test():
    f = A()
    print(f.show_list)


asyncio.run(test())
```

I am trying to run a code like this, the main feature being `show_list` is a property of A, and contains some data to be loaded only when required. However, when running the snippet above, I get these errors:

```
RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'A.load_list' was never awaited
```

How can I keep the property while loading the data on demand?

Comment: Did you mean `asyncio.create_task` instead of `asyncio.run`?

Comment: That doesn't run the task either. I updated my sample to load some data.

Comment: It does run the task. Of course you have to let it run long enough. In your example the main program stops immediately after starting the task.

Comment: Yes because the list is only set after 1 second. Your program does not run for 1 second to make it happen.

Comment: ah so how do I wait for it to finish running?

Comment: For example add `await asyncio.sleep(1.1)` in `test()` after `f.show_list`.

Comment: The issue is I don't know how long the wait will be, this is just a sample of the database call

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should you create properties when using asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984337/how-should-you-create-properties-when-using-asyncio)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247838/discussion-between-weasel-and-mkrieger1).

Comment: This doesn't seem like an appropriate use of the property decorator.   When I write x.y, y may be a variable or property, but I would never expect this line of code to launch an asyncio task and/or block for a significant period of time.  I think it would be better to make show_list a normal member function, and best of all to make it an async function.